# Create Boundary for box2D world object

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, box2d

I have used box2D to make physics effect and here is my set of code

```
    public class Main extends SpriteVisualElement
    {

        public var world:b2World;
        public var wheelArray:Array;
        public var stepTimer:Timer;
        public var scaleFactor:Number = 20; 

        public function Main()
        {
            if (stage) 
                init();
            else 
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            getStarted();
        }

        private function getStarted():void
        {
            var gravity:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(0, 10);
            world = new b2World(gravity, true);
            wheelArray = new Array();

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                createWheel(
                    Math.random() * 0.5,
                    Math.random() * (stage.stageWidth - 20) + 10,
                    Math.random() * (stage.stageHeight - 20) + 10,
                    (Math.random() * 100) - 50,
                    0
                );
            }

            createBoundaries();

            stepTimer = new Timer(0.025 * 1000);
            stepTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTick);
            graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xff0000);
            stepTimer.start();
        }

        private function createBoundaries():void
        {
            trace(this.height,this.width,stage.height,stage.width);
            // need some code here

        }

        protected function onTick(event:TimerEvent):void
        {
            graphics.clear();
            graphics.lineStyle(3, 0xff0000);
            world.Step(0.025, 10, 10);

            for each (var wheelBody:b2Body in wheelArray)
            {
                graphics.drawCircle(
                    wheelBody.GetPosition().x * scaleFactor,
                    wheelBody.GetPosition().y * scaleFactor,
                    (wheelBody.GetFixtureList().GetShape() as b2CircleShape).GetRadius() * scaleFactor
                );

            }
        }


        private function createWheel(radius:Number, startX:Number, startY:Number, velocityX:Number, velocityY:Number):void
        {
            var wheelBodyDef:b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
            wheelBodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;
            wheelBodyDef.position.Set(startX / scaleFactor, startY / scaleFactor);
            var wheelBody:b2Body = world.CreateBody(wheelBodyDef);
            var circleShape:b2CircleShape = new b2CircleShape(radius);
            var wheelFixtureDef:b2FixtureDef = new b2FixtureDef();
            wheelFixtureDef.shape = circleShape;
            wheelFixtureDef.restitution = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.5;
            wheelFixtureDef.friction = (Math.random() * 1.0);
            wheelFixtureDef.density = Math.random() * 20;
            var wheelFixture:b2Fixture = wheelBody.CreateFixture(wheelFixtureDef);

            var startingVelocity:b2Vec2 = new b2Vec2(velocityX, velocityY);
            wheelBody.SetLinearVelocity(startingVelocity);

            wheelArray.push(wheelBody);
        }
    }
}
```

and i have add this to the main view like this

```
var main:Main = new Main();

this.addElement(main);
```

it works but problem in detecting the boundary of the stage.
Objective: i want to set the boundary, so any help ...

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to prevent things from going outside the boundary, or whether you just want to detect that they go outside.

Comment: i want to prevent things from going outside the boundary

Comment: You can set up large static fixtures to function as walls.

Answer (score 1):

Box2D doesn't have a 'boundary'-system as such, you have to

- create bodies/body and place it where you want your boundaries
- Another thing you have to be aware of is **tunneling**. You have to deal with it properly so that no object will pass trough the boundaries. One thing you can do is setting the `bullet`-flag of fast moving objects to true.